# How to create 3D architectural models in this shape with interactive faces?

Tags: graphics3d, interactive

I am a non-technical person in the imageProcessing side,so I don't have any idea how can I make polygon in the below shape...

[image]

the above polygon is a 3D `Graphics` ,if I click on any face of the polygon it will show some message.
I am still working on it,but i didn't get which function is better out of this `Cuboid` and `Polygon`

can you give any suggestions on this?

Comment: You can't cut holes in a `Cuboid[]`, so your best bet is using `Polygon`s. It's not going to be easy, but it isn't all that difficult either — just some tedious geometry. You'll have to, of course, figure out the 3D points for the different faces and the roofs and then you can use `Texture[]` to tile the roof. However, I would strongly suggest against using Mathematica for this. It might be far simpler to create this in something like AutoCAD or even Google Sketchup Pro and then import it into Mathematica.

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks for your information....

Comment: If this was created in 3DS Max - [this](http://www.moddb.com/games/vector-thrust/forum/thread/wip-storage-building) suggests it might be - then suitable follow-up questions could include "How can I import 3DS files that retain surface textures?" or "How can I edit 3DS files in Mathematica?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a basic code to get textures and "click on any face to show message" features:

```
Graphics3D[{

  {Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "Metal4"}]],
   PopupWindow[
    Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}],
    Style["metallic floor", 18]]},

  {Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "Roof"}]], EdgeForm[],
   PopupWindow[
    Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0,
         1, 1}}],
    Style["brick roof", 18]] }

  }, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Now for sophisticated designs look at demonstrations:

- [**Block Builder**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BlockBuilder/)
- [**Hello Block World**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HelloBlockWorld/)
- [**Architecture**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Architecture)
- [**Sándor Kabai**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/author.html?author=S%C3%A1ndor%20Kabai)
- [**London Eye**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LondonEye/)
- [**Building Frame with Catenary Roof Beams**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BuildingFrameWithCatenaryRoofBeams/)
- [**Openable Cosine Dome**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/OpenableCosineDome/)

[image]